# Pandas, drop duplicates across multiple columns only if None in other column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

For a large dataset (>800 000 records), need to find duplicates across multiple columns but delete if only it has None in a separate column.

For example in this case we searching for duplicates by subset=['Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'] and checking None in Col1:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| None | a    |    2 |    1 |
| i1   | a    |    2 |    1 |
| i2   | v    |    7 |    5 |
| i3   | b    |    1 |    3 |
| None | c    |    2 |    2 |
| i4   | b    |    1 |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

We should remove only first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) chained by `|` for bitwise `Or` with all duplicates by `keep=False` by columns in [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = df[df['Col1'].notna() | ~df.duplicated(subset=['Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], keep=False) ]
print (df)
   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
1    i1    a     2     1
2    i2    v     7     5
3    i3    b     1     3
4  None    c     2     2
5    i4    b     1     3
```

Comment: jezrael, thanks! You literally nail any pandas-related question!
I did slightly different way, just deleted following records: 
df[(df.duplicated(subset = ["Col2", "Col3", "Col4",], keep=False)) & (df['Col1']==None)]

Comment: @Oleksii - No, there is a lof of question.